# Removing a specific element from a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, it moves every element in the class "block" 10 pixels to the left. I want it to remove any of the elements which are left of 300 pixels. Why does `$(this).remove()` not work and what can I do to fix this?

```
    $(".block").animate({left:"-=10"},speed,"linear",function(){

        if(parseInt(this.style.left) < 300)
        {
            $(this).remove();
            //something
        }else{
            //something
        }
    });
```

html:

```
    <div id="container">
       <span class="block"></span>
       <span class="block"></span>
    </div>
```

Here's all of my code http://jsbin.com/ExET/1/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cmvUZ/

Comment: @JosephSilber for me, the elements have the class "block" they aren't within the class "block"

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference. I just used it  to show where stuff is moving. Can you post a fiddle of your code that is not working? Be sure to only provide the code relevant to this question: [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Extending @JosephSilber fiddle, I got this, Kind of working, click in body to see the animation http://jsfiddle.net/cmvUZ/1/

Comment: @JakeSchievink, do you want to remove elements from the class, or from the DOM?

Comment: @AkhilSekharan looks good, but im using span instead of div and it breaks for me when I change the div tags to span Heres all of my code http://jsbin.com/ExET/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGVPb/3/)**

```
$('div').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).animate({ 
        left: '+=10' 
    }, 200, 'linear', function() {
        if($(this).offset().left > 50) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            $(this).css('background', 'blue');
        }   
    });
});
```

You will need to change the values but it achieves the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:
http://jsbin.com/olipOh/4/watch?html,css,js,output

You need to select child elements:

```
$(".block").find("*")
```